# modulo with n instead of 0 without using if-statement

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is there a way to to express the following without using an if statement, but with mathematical operations instead?

{ 5 if x % 5 = 0, x % 5 otherwise }

Comment: `Mod[x-1,5]+1`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the 3rd offset argument of `Mod` for this:

```
Mod[x, 5, 1]
```

The 3rd argument effectively shifts the point where `Mod` loops back. So `Mod[x, 5, 0]` loops from 0 to 4 and `Mod[x, 5, 1]` loops from 1 to 5.